# Can we customize street colours in google maps api in any way

Tags: android, google-maps

My question involves google maps api knowledge . I want to use google maps in my android app to display roads / streets in different colours. How i do that? Can i customize the street colours on google map api in any way?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to customize street colors and had any problems?

Comment: No i havnt tried customizing street colours..but i need this functionality in my ptoject work. So i needed advice

Answer (score 2):

yes we can.Now google actually offer this.

but before that you have to spend some time in understanding few things like:

- How this works.

Follow this order to read and understand:- go through these links(advised to proceed in order to have a batter understanding)

1. have a look at this (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)
2. here is a example for understanding how it works (https://medium.com/exploring-android/introducing-custom-map-styles-for-google-maps-be2095c38850)
3. finally google offical link to create customisated json map file(link is given in comment as i am not allowed to post more then 2 link(sorry)).

note: usage of this tool is also shown in second step in example.

Comment: Link to of the tool (https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)